# Making mdframed paragraph behave like normal paragraphs in terms of spacing

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, mdframed

I'm using the `mdframed` package to highlight a paragraph with rules on both sides. However, the `mdframed`-environment creates a box for the paragraph inside of it and so the spacing around it is different form the spacing of a normal paragraph.

The following code shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\parindent=0pt
\newenvironment{note}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=\dimexpr-0.5em-3pt, innerleftmargin=0.5em,
                     rightmargin=\dimexpr-0.5em-3pt, innerrightmargin=0.5em,
                     linewidth=3pt,linecolor=red, topline=false, bottomline=false]%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\Huge XYZ

XYZ

\begin{note}
XYZ
\end{note}

XYZ

xyz

\begin{note}
xyz
\end{note}

xyz
\end{document}
```

I guess the problem can be fixed with adjusting the inner margin/skip options for the `mdframed` environment, but it seems rather tricky to find the correct values to make it behave *exactly* like a normal paragraph. Any ideas how to get the natural paragraph spacing for that?

EDIT: To make it more clear, the prolematic part is the line-spacing before and after the framed paragraph. You can see the problem best when selecting a big font size and short paragraphs. In my example the framed block starts right at the bottom of text in the paragraph before it, but there should be some additional space/glue between both.

The opposite problem occurs at the bottom of the framed paragraph, there's too much space between it and the following paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  Your MWE works as far as I can tell.  You got the correct values by setting your `leftmargin` to a negative combination of the `linewidth` and `innerleftmargin`; similarly for the `rightmargin`.  What am I missing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It might be a little clearer (in the output) if you use the `lipsum` package to insert some sample text

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. Sorry that my question wasn't clear enough, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed,lipsum}

\parindent=0pt
\newmdenv[leftmargin=\dimexpr-0.5em-3pt, innerleftmargin=0.5em,
          rightmargin=\dimexpr-0.5em-3pt, innerrightmargin=0.5em,
          linewidth=3pt,linecolor=red, topline=false, bottomline=false,
          innertopmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,skipbelow=0pt,skipabove=0pt,
         ]{notex}
\newenvironment{note}
 {\par\vskip\dimexpr\dp\strutbox-\prevdepth\relax\notex\strut\ignorespaces}
 {\par\xdef\notetpd{\the\prevdepth}\endnotex\vskip-\notetpd\relax}

\begin{document}
\leavevmode\llap{\smash{\vrule depth7\baselineskip height0pt\hskip1em}}%
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{note}
\lipsum[2]
\end{note}
\leavevmode\llap{\smash{\vrule height\baselineskip\hskip1em}}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The black rules are just to show that the alignment is correct (they can't be too near the text because `mdframed` applies a white background).

[image]

A magnified view of the top line

[image]

And one of the bottom line

[image]

At the start we ensure to skip by the glue TeX would insert and we add a strut to the first line in the `note` environment, so to have the correct distance between baselines. At the end we do similarly, keeping into account the depth of the last line in the `note` environment.

### Brief explanation

`mdframed` sets its chunks in a `\vbox` which is inserted in the main vertical list; this usually upsets the interline spacing, as a `\vbox` has its reference point at the baseline of the last box inside it. The package tries to do clever things not to add unwanted spaces, but in this case it's not sufficient.

So we need to emulate TeX's normal behavior. The distance from one baseline and the next is the sum of `\dp\strutbox` and `\ht\strutbox`; we can insert a strut in the first line of `note` which makes it the correct height; but adding `\dp\strutbox` vertical space will usually be too much, because the last line before `note` may have descenders. So we end the paragraph so that `\prevdepth` (an internal parameter) contains the depth of the last contributed box (precisely the last line). So we can add

```
\vskip\dp\strutbox-\prevdepth
```

and all is good. Something similar we have to do at the end. We end the paragraph and define `\notetpd` to contain the value of `\prevdepth`, so we can remove a vertical space with that amount, putting everything back in synch.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer! I understand what you do at the beginning of the framed paragraph, but could you please explain what happens at the end? Where does the space we have to remove come from?

Comment: @siracusa Happy to have helped. I like your nickname; or it's the real name? Siracusa is a wonderful town and I've always been a fan of Archimedes. :)

Comment: It's not my real name, but it was chosen after that town. Incidentally, it has its origins in one of the operas from the composer you cite in your profile (which I'm a big fan of). :-)

Answer (score 3):

By using the command `\mdflength` you can set the `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` and just focus on the other parameters or not bother to set them at all and still get the spacing correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%  This takes the approach of your MWE where you set the widths of the
%%  line and margins
\newenvironment{mynoteA}{\noindent\hspace*{\parindent}}{}
\surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=3pt,
                      linecolor=red,
                      topline=false,bottomline=false,
                       innerleftmargin=0.5em,innerrightmargin=0.5em,
                      leftmargin=\dimexpr-\mdflength{linewidth}-\mdflength{innerleftmargin},
                      rightmargin=\dimexpr-\mdflength{linewidth}-\mdflength{innerrightmargin}]{mynoteA}
%%  Here you let `mdframed` decide the values of linewidth and inner
%%  margins, but still the frame is set correctly.
\newenvironment{mynoteB}{\noindent\hspace*{\parindent}}{}
\surroundwithmdframed[linecolor=red,
                      topline=false,bottomline=false,
                      leftmargin=\dimexpr-\mdflength{linewidth}-\mdflength{innerleftmargin},
                      rightmargin=\dimexpr-\mdflength{linewidth}-\mdflength{innerrightmargin}]{mynoteB}
%%
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\textbf{\Large{}No frame:}\par
\lipsum[1]

\textbf{\Large{}Here you preset the margins:}
\begin{mynoteA}%
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mynoteA}

\textbf{\Large{}Here you let \texttt{mdframed} choose the lengths}
\begin{mynoteB}%
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mynoteB}

\end{document}
```

There is a slight problem which becomes apparent when you don't set `\parindent` to `0pt`.  I've tried to patch it:  I added the `\hspace*{\parindent}` to get the paragraph to indent correctly: it will work as you expect when to set `\parindent` to `0pt`.

This is the result.

[image]

I chose to use `\surroundwithmdframed` to separate the formatting you want for the content from the formatting you want for the frame.  You don't have to go this route.  You can put it all in an environment like you did in your MWE.

Per your editted question, there are several more parameters you can play with to create a visual effect closer to what you want:  `innertopmargin` and `skipabove` and their cousins for the bottom.