# Wrong vertical alignment using mdframed with tight margins

Tags: spacing, mdframed

When using the `mdframed` environment with absolutely tight margins (all set 0pt), there is too much negative vertical space of split md-frames that are placed at the top of a page.

To illustrate this, the minimal working example creates two text pages, the second of which contains text in an md-frame, clearly not aligned with the text in the first page.

I created the example using a command `\FOO`, which calls an environment `valignFOO` that contains the actual mdframed environment named `mdframedFOO`, the latter of which has margin sizes of zero and a small frame for visual reference.

`valignFOO` is responsible for [Making mdframed paragraph behave like normal paragraphs in terms of spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88525/making-mdframed-paragraph-behave-like-normal-paragraphs-in-terms-of-spacing). But even by using that improvement with respect to vertical spacing, I still observe extra space as described above.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a6paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% New mdframed environment called mdframedFOO:
\newmdenv[leftmargin        = 0pt,
          rightmargin       = 0pt,
          innerleftmargin   = 0pt,
          innerrightmargin  = 0pt,
          innertopmargin    = 0pt,
          innerbottommargin = 0pt,
          skipabove         = 0pt,
          skipbelow         = 0pt,
          splittopskip      = 0pt,
          splitbottomskip   = 0pt,
          outerlinewidth    = 1pt,
          middlelinewidth   = 0pt,
          innerlinewidth    = 0pt,
          topline           = false,
          bottomline        = false
         ]{mdframedFOO}

% Correct vertical alignment of mdframedFOO:
% (This is for making mdframed behave like a normal paragraph,
%  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88525/making-mdframed-paragraph-behave-like-normal-paragraphs-in-terms-of-spacing)
\newenvironment{valignFOO}
 {\par\vskip\dimexpr\dp\strutbox-\prevdepth\relax\mdframedFOO\strut\ignorespaces}
 {\par\xdef\notetpd{\the\prevdepth}\endmdframedFOO\vskip-\notetpd\relax}

% FOO:
\newcommand{\FOO}[1]{%
  \begin{valignFOO}
    #1
  \end{valignFOO}
}




\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
  \FOO{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not seeing additional vertical spacing at the top of the 2nd page. The output I get is [here](http://i.imgur.com/3VBwW3m.png).